# How do I create a data frame into an edgelist with two columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I had a specific question about turning my data into two columns so I can make an edgelist. I've attached a screenshot of the data. There's up to V10, and each row represents artists that have worked on the same song. I wanted to create an edgelist with the artist names. For example, for rows that have person A, B, C, D, I wanted to create:

A B

A C

A D

B C

B D

C D

The code I used so far is:

`reltest <- t(do.call(cbind, lapply(cleanartists[sapply(cleanartists, length) >= 2], combn, 2)))`

But this gives me all possible combinations among the artist names, not just the ones that have existing relationships. This is what my data looks like:

```
 > head(cleanartists, n = 20)
                        V1                        V2              V3              V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10
1             Bethel Music              Jenn Johnson            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2                Gal Costa            Caetano Veloso            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3                     JAYZ                Kanye West            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4                     2Pac                 Danny Boy            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
5                 Ludacris                   Shawnna            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
6         Richard Armitage            The Dwarf Cast            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
7                 Ludacris                     TPain            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
8   The Velvet Underground                  Lou Reed            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
9     The Stanley Brothers  The Clinch Mountain Boys            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
10      The Carter Sisters           Mother Maybelle            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
11               Lady Gaga              Colby ODonis            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
12                 Rihanna                      JAYZ            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
13              Lil Yachty              Trippie Redd            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
14              Brian Tuey            James McCawley  Kevin Sherwood  Treyarch Sound <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
15   Sister Rosetta Tharpe              The Rosettes            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
16             Bing Crosby       The Andrews Sisters            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
17            Stone Poneys            Linda Ronstadt            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
18                  J Cole                     Drake            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
19 The Last Shadow Puppets               Alex Turner      Miles Kane            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
20               Gal Costa            Caetano Veloso            <NA>            <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Maybe something like this then just drop the NA values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690478/r-combine-multiple-columns-as-pairs-of-column-cells-in-same-row

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894773/reshaping-k-columns-to-2-columns-representing-sequential-pairs-of-the-values-of

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742468/create-edgelist-for-all-interactions-from-data-frame

Comment: Very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782132/create-edge-list-from-ragged-data-frame-in-r-for-network-analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping with rbase functions, but adding magrittr (`%>%`) to make the code more readable, try this:

```
# add the pipe (%>%) operator
library(magrittr)

# tibble just to make an dataset easily
dtf <- tibble::tribble(
  ~V1, ~V2, ~V3, ~V4, ~V5,
  "A", "B", NA, NA, NA,
  "A", "B", "C", NA, NA,
  "D", "E", "F", NA, NA,
  "F", "G", NA, NA, NA
) %>% as_data_frame()


dtf %>% 
  apply(., 1, function(.x){   # for each row in the dataset
    .x[!is.na(.x)] %>%        # as char vector, remove the NA values
      combn(2) %>%            # make combinations of 2 of the elements 
      t() %>%                 # transpose the matrix output of combn
      as.data.frame()         # transform the matrix in a data frame
  }) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .)           # bind the data dataframes
```

You'll get:

```
  V1 V2
1  A  B
2  A  B
3  A  C
4  B  C
5  D  E
6  D  F
7  E  F
8  F  G
```

same as the code:

```
# without '%>%' operator
do.call(rbind,apply(dtf, 1, function(.x){as.data.frame(t(combn(.x[!is.na(.x)],2)))}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to apply your function to every row, and then only take the elements that are not `NA`. And with the approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574006/unique-rows-considering-two-columns-in-r-without-order) you can get rid of duplicates.

```
test_data <- data.frame(V1 = c("A", "D"),
                        V2 = c("B", "B"),
                        V3 = c("C", NA),
                        V4 = c("D", NA),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

combinations <- t(do.call("cbind", apply(test_data, 1, function(x) combn(x[!is.na(x)], 2))))

library(dplyr)
combinations_cleaned <- data.frame(combinations, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(key = paste0(pmin(X1, X2), pmax(X1, X2), sep = "")) %>%
  distinct(key, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-key)

combinations_cleaned
  key
1  AB
2  AC
3  AD
4  BC
5  BD
6  CD
```